# Creating 2D gameboard/ grid in Unity with C#

Tags: c#, grid

I'm new to Unity and programming and I'm trying to make this game with moving cars on gameboard. My idea is to create an array and somehow store information about each element or tile in this array. I'd like these tiles to be able to be referenced to later, e.g. to detect if there is car GO on specific tile or not, etc. Unfortunately I¨m struggling how exactly should I save information to a tile so I can reference to it later, I mean later when I create a method which should be able to detect if that tile is occupied or not.
Thank you for all advices in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot write code for you.Please look for some board game tutorials like this one: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike/boardmanager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below adds buttons to a panel control. You can replace the button with an image to use in your games.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int ROWS = 10;
        const int COLS = 15;
        const int WIDTH = 20;
        const int HEIGHT = 20;
        const int SPACE = 10;
        List<List<MyButton>> buttons = new List<List<MyButton>>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
            {
                List<MyButton> newRow = new List<MyButton>();
                buttons.Add(newRow);

                for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
                {
                    MyButton newButton = new MyButton();
                    newRow.Add(newButton);

                    newButton.Width = WIDTH;
                    newButton.Height = HEIGHT;
                    newButton.Left = col * (WIDTH + SPACE);
                    newButton.Top = row * (HEIGHT + SPACE);

                    newButton.row = row;
                    newButton.col = col;

                    panel1.Controls.Add(newButton);
                }
            }


        }
    }
    public class MyButton : Button
    {
        public int row { get; set; }
        public int col { get; set; }
    }
}
```